# ValueEventListener is assigned to the right path but is it not reading the value of the child node, though returns the right key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am making an attendance application for my college, where in to redirect user to their correct home activity based on what role they carry. To do the same, I have made 3 service classes, User-Role-Service, Faculty-Data-Service and Student-Data-Service.

In, User-Role-Service singleton, it is reading the role of the user using it's 'uid' from firebase database. And according to the value returned it calls the function in Faculty-Data-Service or Student-Data-Service singleton to store user information.User-Role-Service Code:-

```js
fun getRole (complete:(Boolean) -> Unit) {
        val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        val user = auth.currentUser?.uid
        val ref = mDatabaseReference.child("Users").child(user)
        println(ref)
        if( user != null) {//[Start : of Null Check]
            //[Start : of ValueEventListener Object] --> func# 2
            mValueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
                    dataSnapshot?.children?.forEach {
                        role = it.child("role").value.toString()
                        if(role == "faculty"){
                            FacultyDataService.storeFacultyData(it) {
                                when(it){
                                    true -> complete(true)
                                    false -> Log.d(TAG, "FacultyDataService.storeFacultyData() failed")
                                }
                            }
                        } else if(role == "student"){
                            StudentDataService.storeStudentData(it) {
                                when(it){
                                    true -> complete(true)
                                    false -> Log.d(TAG, "StudentDataService.storeStudentData() failed")
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG,"Role is neither student nor faculty.")
                        }
                    }//[End : forEach.]
                }//[End : onDataChanged]
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "VEL database error")
                    complete(false)
                }//[End : ^]
            }//[End : func# 2.]
        }//[End : of Null Check]
        else{
            Log.d(TAG, "authToken is null")
        }
        ref.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener)
    }
}
```

This is the Log message that I am getting :

> D/UserRoleService: Role is neither student nor faculty.

I believe this is happening because it is not reading the value of the child node. But then it is at the right path as when I log the path it returns the right path and also returns the key of the child.
I am not sure where I am going wrong, please guide.

Firebase Structure here.

[image]

Also, I am passing the DataSnapshot as an argument to storeFacultyData(ds) and storeStudentData(ds) functions. Can that possibly creat any issue?

Comment: What are you getting here: `role = it.child("role").value.toString()`. Also can you add a sample of your database as text?

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/meQCj.png here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping over the children of the resulting snapshot. Such a loop is only needed when you can potentially have multiple results, which is not the case here. Since you are directly reading the node of the specific user you want to load, there is only one result.

So remove the loop and you should be good:

```
override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
    role = it.child("role").value.toString()
    if(role == "faculty"){
        FacultyDataService.storeFacultyData(it) {
            when(it){
                true -> complete(true)
                false -> Log.d(TAG, "FacultyDataService.storeFacultyData() failed")
            }
        }
    } else if(role == "student"){
        StudentDataService.storeStudentData(it) {
            when(it){
                true -> complete(true)
                false -> Log.d(TAG, "StudentDataService.storeStudentData() failed")
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG,"Role is neither student nor faculty. It is: "+role)
    }
}//[End : onDataChanged]
```